# How do Asp.Net.Mvc git tags correlate to the git revision?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, open-source

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0` and would like to link the debugger to the exact source code. I have the [aspnetwebstack repo](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) cloned locally but can't quite figure out which revision this corresponds to.

I see lots of tags in the git repo but none of them seem to be for this version (or maybe they're versioning things differently?)

Here's what I see in the repo

[image: No v5.0 tag as expected in aspnetwebstack git]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those version numbers seem to align with the version numbers for System.Web.WebPages and System.Web.Razor.

The [Guide for upgrading MVC 4 to MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) has System.Web.WebPages and System.Web.Razor 2.0.x.x corresponding with MVC 4 (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.x.x), and 3.0.0 corresponding with MVC 5 (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0).

The MVC version can be found in the `src\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs` or `src\CommonAssemblyInfo.vb`, and indeed selecting the v3.0 branch shows MVC version 5.0.0.0

Comment: I see. That makes (some) sense. I'm going to suggest a chart on their codeplex

Answer (score 2):

George the best way to deal with it is to use the symbol packages rather than cloning the repo.

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debug%20Official%20Symbols%20and%20Source

The tags are mapped as @jmoerdyk is suggesting. See this table for more info - https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20from%20Source